# ActiveRecord querying a tree structure efficiently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, activerecord

I have inherited a Rails 3 app that stores much of it's data as a fairly sophisticated tree structure. The application works pretty well in general but we are noticing some problems with performance, mostly around database interactions.

I am seeing a lot of queries along the lines of these showing up in my logs:

```
SELECT `messages`.* FROM `messages` WHERE `messages`.`context_type` = 'Node' AND `messages`.`context_id` IN (153740, 153741, /* about a thousand records... */ 154837, 154838, 154839, 154840, 154841, 154842, 154843)
```

Followed by many single queries where it looks as though the same record is being queried time and again:

```
[1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `plans`.* FROM `plans` WHERE `plans`.`type` IN ('Scenario') AND `plans`.`id` = 1435 LIMIT 1
```

My log has that exact query roughly eighty times- now I'm guessing that initial `Cache` message means it is probably being pulled from a cache rather than going back to the database every time, but it still looks like a lot and this type of thing is happening repeatedly.

I am guessing that the above queries are an association being pulled out backwards so that `message belongs_to plan` and it is loading all the messages then pulling out the plan for each one rather than, as one might do in a sane world, starting with the plan and then loading all the messages.

Working in this vein, a single request contains **1641 SELECT statements** and it seems very likely to me that the sheer amount of database traffic ( not to mention the number of sequential `LIMIT 1` queries for neighbouring data in the same table ) is a significant bottleneck. I am reluctant to post too much code but this is a typical example of one of the larger queries:

```
 def nodes
    include_objects = [:sector, :market, :messages, :node_user_prefs, :reference_node, :project, {:available_events => :available_event_nodes}, :customer_factors, :active_components, :tags, { :event_histories => :node}, {:event_histories => :user }]

    project = self
    @cached_nodes ||= begin
      all_nodes = orig_nodes.includes(include_objects)
      all_nodes = all_nodes.map { |n| n.tap { |i| i.cached_project = project } }
      all_node_ids = all_nodes.map(&:id)
      all_nodes.select{ |n| n.type == 'InitialNode' || all_node_ids.include?(n.parent_node_id) } 
    end
  end
```

Obviously, the queries are pretty diverse and the application is large, but this is fairly representative of the standard approach taken.

What are the easy wins with ActiveRecord that I can use to try and speed things up? I can easily enough put together a query that would pull all the required data out in a single round trip, but how easy would it be to form that - redundancies and all - into my model hierarchy? What other techniques can I use to help out here?

Answer (score 0):

**Ancestry Gem**

Not a direct fix by any means, but you may wish to consider the [`ancestry` gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) -

This will give you a way to create a tree structure, whereby you'll be able to call single records & then have their descendents called a you wish. This will cut back on your SQL queries:

[image]

If you set up your nodes / objects in this fashion, it will allow you to call the records you require once & ancestry will populate the rest. If you want me to divulge more information on this, please let me know in the comments & I'll detail more specifics

Comment: That looks like a pretty great option for what I would need if I was building the application from scratch, but right now I don't have that liberty and it looks like it would be pretty hard to refactor into this existing system, though I would be interested to hear if that was incorrect.

Comment: You'll basically have to change all the records in the db to inherit using the column declared by the `ancestry` gem in the model