# Preload complete set of deep relationships in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, activerecord

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24651295/activerecord-querying-a-tree-structure-efficiently), I have a situation where I have a heirarchy of objects in my Rails 3 application that is perhaps eight relationships deep, mostly through `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationships, so for example: A `project has_many users`, `user has_many permissions`, a `project has_many nodes`, a `node belongs_to permission`, a `node has_many properties`, a `property has_many edit_histories` and so on. It's all fairly standard stuff, but there is a fair amount of it. This is an application which is already in production, so that architecture is one I am currently tied to.

The problem I am having is that sometimes ( for example when we open a Project ) I want to eager-load pretty much everything, and other times I don't. So I don't want everything to be eager-loaded by default. When I do want everything, in spite of a serious list of preloads, I'm running into some serious N+1 problems, to the point that loading a single page is enacting hundreds of queries and in some situations requests simply time out. Using [Bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) has not shown any obvious missing `include` statements on my relationships but when I look at the SQL that is being generated one thing I notice is some enormous "IN" queries with hundreds of ids on them- although they are working with a primary key, that seems like a clunky way to retrieve data.

If I was writing something like this from scratch I would probably put together a single sophisticated SQL statement that pulled out all the data in one shot ( based on some things I know but ActiveRecord probably doesn't ) and then match up the relationships afterwards. Obviously that would break the whole database agnostic thing, but right now pages timing out is going to trouble our users a lot less even if they did care about the purity of a Rails application, which they don't. My question is:

Is there a way of doing something like this in ActiveRecord or a gem that would be able to help? Are there any other ways of minimising the number of queries that are performed or any other tricks to bring this very hierarchical data back in a timely fashion?

Answer (score 2):

If you just use :includes, rails will choose an include strategy, which is not allways what you intended. This can result in eager loading things you don't actually need. Eager loading associated records by their id's is just one option it chooses. Sometimes it's better than joining, sometimes not and sometimes it includes what you didn't want.

See [Tricks Rails didn't tell you about](https://speakerdeck.com/carlosantoniodasilva/tricks-that-rails-didnt-tell-you-about-at-railsconf-2014)#Eager load Strategies.

There is no gem that could help here, because this is a very use case specific problem. 
Plz post another question, with a specific problem, describing what exact data should be displayed on the page and how your models lool like. Pls provide some pseudo code, showing the consumption of Active Record data, which produce the n+1 queries.

Additionally, i can say rails is really bad at processing large data sets. Perhaps you should be just displaying less entries or even use a custom sql query if this is no option

**Edit 1:** 
Examples to address your question about optional eager loading

```
#class Project

#scope
def self.with_full_users
  includes(:users => {:permisions => :nodes})
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I know it will eager load a lot of stuff that I don't need in some cases - that is why I was saying I don't want to automatically include everything by default - I was wondering whether there were clever tricks with scopes or similar that might be able to help here- maybe a way for a scope to call scoped relationships, but it doesn't sound like there are. I don't see that wanting to load in a bunch of data across deep relationships is that specific to my situation though and the trouble with simplifying models enough for an SO question is that the problem arises from complexity :(

Comment: Sure there are options to not eager load everything by default. The simplest way is to define a cusom scope, calling the right includes. You can also define a new relationship with another name e.g. `has_many :included_users` , then confugure it to eager_load and provide the User classname, because it now won't follow the rails defaults